# Selecting Items from another table using ID

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two tables `Item` and a table which records the items in each order (Junction Table)

**ITEM Table**

```
String itemTable = "CREATE TABLE " + ITEM_TABLE + " ("
        + ID_ITEM + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + ITEM_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + ITEM_TYPE + " TEXT,"
        + ITEM_PRICE + " TEXT);";
```

**ORDER_ITEM Table**

```
String orderItemTable = "CREATE TABLE " + ORDER_ITEM_TABLE + " ("
        + ID_ORDER_ITEM + " INTEGER,"
        + ID_ITEM_ORDER + " INTEGER,"
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+ID_ORDER_ITEM+") REFERENCES "+ EMP_TABLE +"("+ ID_EMP +"), "
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+ID_ITEM_ORDER+") REFERENCES "+ EMP_TABLE +"("+ ID_EMP +"));";
```

Data in the `ORDER_ITEM` table each `Item` id refers to a specific item in the item table this is what I am trying to refer to and use to pull data from the `DB`.

[image]

At the moment I can pull the `Item id` from this table but not the actual `Item` using the Id. Here `idOrder` is passed when the order is selected

```
String selctAllEmployeesOrdersItems = "SELECT * FROM " + ORDER_ITEM_TABLE + " WHERE " + ID_ORDER_ITEM + " = " + idOrder;
```

One way of achieving what I want is by storing the `Item ID's` in a `ArrayList` and iterating over this to select all of the `Items` but I know there is a better way.

Some research I have seen has suggested that I join the tables referencing the `ITEM ID` but I am not sure of the correct syntax. The dot notation does not work with this query.

```
String selctAllEmployeesOrdersItems = "SELECT * FROM " + ORDER_ITEM_TABLE + " WHERE " + ID_ORDER_ITEM + " = " + idOrder
        + " JOIN " + ITEM_TABLE + " ON " + ORDER_ITEM_TABLE+"."+ID_ITEM_ORDER + " = " + ITEM_TABLE+"."+ID_ITEM;
```

The error message being show is

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "JOIN":
> syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM
> ORDER_ITEM_TABLE WHERE ID_Order = 1 JOIN ITEM_TABLE ON
> ORDER_ITEM_TABLE.ID_Item = ITEM_TABLE.ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your SQL statement is wrong.
The `WHERE` clause must be written after the join:

```
String selctAllEmployeesOrdersItems = 
  "SELECT * FROM " + ORDER_ITEM_TABLE + " AS o " + 
  "INNER JOIN " + ITEM_TABLE + " AS i ON o." + ID_ITEM_ORDER + " = i." + ID_ITEM + " " +
  "WHERE o." + ID_ORDER_ITEM + " = " + idOrder;
```

Note the use of aliases `o` and `i` for the 2 tables that shortens significantly the code.

Also, the definition of the table `ORDER_ITEM`:

```
String orderItemTable = "CREATE TABLE " + ORDER_ITEM_TABLE + " ("
        + ID_ORDER_ITEM + " INTEGER,"
        + ID_ITEM_ORDER + " INTEGER,"
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+ID_ORDER_ITEM+") REFERENCES "+ EMP_TABLE +"("+ ID_EMP +"), "
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+ID_ITEM_ORDER+") REFERENCES "+ EMP_TABLE +"("+ ID_EMP +"));";
```

does not seem correct.
What is the table `EMP_TABLE`?
Why do both columns `ID_ORDER_ITEM` and `ID_ITEM_ORDER` reference the same column?
This does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the clauses in the wrong order, this should be:
select ... from ... join ... on ... where ...
So in this case:

```
SELECT * FROM
ORDER_ITEM_TABLE JOIN ITEM_TABLE
ON ORDER_ITEM_TABLE.ID_Item = ITEM_TABLE.ID
WHERE ORDER_ITEM_TABLE.ID_Order=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause goes after the join. I would also recommend using table aliases to shorten the query and make it more readable. Finally, you probably want to select columns from the items table only, not from the junction table (which you are filtering on already):

```
SELECT i.*
FROM ORDER_ITEM_TABLE oi 
JOIN ITEM_TABLE i ON oi.ID_Item = i.ID
WHERE oi.ID_Order = 1
```